# Loop and export only one tab

Tags: loops, google-apps-script

I have a script that's working well - it takes a value from a list (employee ID) and inserts it into the 'Scorecard' tab - the script then outputs all employee scorecards as .pdfs. Only problem I'm running into is the script is exporting both tabs to the .pdf as opposed to only the scorecard... any thoughts?

```
function loop() {
  var targetFolderId = "11rc9rFM25lnLArxm0yk588UEH5MD-NpR";
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId); 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var validation_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Performance_Scores');
  var lastRow = validation_sheet.getLastRow();
  var inputs = ss.getSheetByName('Performance_Scores').getRange('A2:A'+lastRow).getValues();
  var tab = ss.getSheetByName('Scorecard');

  //Loop
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    tab.getRange('B2').setValue(inputs[i][0]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(5000);

  //Print PDFs
  var name = tab.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  targetFolder.createFile(ss.getAs('application/pdf')).setName(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: So do you wish to simply eliminate the pdfs?

Comment: Just the second page of the .pdf - currently it is printing both tabs (Performance_Score, Scorecards) and I only want it to print one tab (Scorecards)

Comment: How about hiding Performance_Score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function loop() {
  var targetFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById("11rc9rFM25lnLArxm0yk588UEH5MD-NpR"); 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var validation_sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Performance_Scores').hideSheet();
  var inputs=validation_sheet.getRange(2,1,validation_sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var tab=ss.getSheetByName('Scorecard').showSheet();
  for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    tab.getRange('B2').setValue(inputs[i][0]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
    var name=tab.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
    targetFolder.createFile(ss.getAs('application/pdf')).setName(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked - thank you so much, Cooper! SO helpful - I knew it was a quick fix but could not figure it out for the life of me. Appreciate it!

Comment: When creating pdf like that it uses all of the visible sheets.  So hiding the sheets you don't want does the trick.

Comment: Makes sense - really appreciate your help on this!